# Sum values ​of an array

Tags: jquery, typescript

Good day everyone, I've the following problem, I've some arrays with information about different products, each product has a rating, when I want to take that assessment and make an average to rate the store, it does not recognize the values.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I could improve?
Thank you
[image]

This is my Typscript

```
 Review(i, totalReviews) {

      let globalRating = 0;
      let globalReviews = 0;

      setTimeout(function () {

        totalReviews.forEach((review, index) => {

          globalRating += review.length;

          for (const i in review) {

            globalReviews += review[i].review;

            console.log("I", review[i]);

          }
        })
        console.log("Raiting", globalRating);
        console.log("globalReviews", globalReviews);

        let averageReviews = Math.round(globalReviews / globalRating);
        let precentage = Math.round(globalReviews * 100 / (globalRating * 5));
        let averageRating = DinamicReviews.fnc(averageReviews);

        $(".br-theme-fontawesome-stars").html(`

        <select class="ps-rating reviewsOption" data-read-only="true"></select>

        `)

        for (let i = 0; i < averageRating.length; i++) {

          $(".reviewsOption").append(`

          <option value="${averageRating[i]}">${i + 1}</option>

          `)

        }

        Rating.fnc();

      }, i * 100)
  }
```

Comment: Multiple issues here, but your NaN issue is at `globalRating += review.length;` `review` here is an object and `length` will be `undefined`

Comment: What I do is that I do a search in `Firebase RD` I get the main array that I will call `product` and each one has a field which is `store` and `review`
By obtaining the information of `Sotre 1` with its`reviews`,  I want to calculate how good the store is.
The problem is that the result it brings is NaN
`(parameter) review: any`
`lenght: any`
The idea is that I go through the array taking the value of review and that I performed the operation.

I wanna know, what other issues i have?

Answer (score 2):

ES5 introduced the super awesome `reduce` method for arrays.

> The reduce() method executes a user-supplied “reducer” callback
> function on each element of the array, passing in the return value
> from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of
> running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single
> value.
>
> Perhaps the easiest-to-understand case for reduce() is to return the
> sum of all the elements in an array.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

It's a little unclear what the global reviews are as well as rating. Where does the number 15 come from?

Anyhow, you could do something like this:

```js
const array = [
    {review: 4, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 5, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 4, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 3, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 4, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 5, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 5, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 4, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 5, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 4, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 3, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 4, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 5, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' },
    {review: 5, comment: 'Lorem Ipsum' }
];

const getAvrgRating = (arr) => {
    return Math.round(arr.reduce((total, obj) => obj.review + total,0) / arr.length);
};

const getGlobalRating = (arr) => {
    return arr.length;
};

const getPercentage = (partial, total) => {
    if (partial === 0 && total === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return Math.round((partial / total) * 100);
};

const rateStore = (arr) => {
    console.log(`Global rating: ${getGlobalRating(arr)}`);
    console.log(`Average rating: ${getAvrgRating(arr)}`);
    console.log(`Percentage: ${getPercentage(getAvrgRating(arr), getGlobalRating(arr))}`);
};

rateStore(array);
```

The overall logic should be applicable to your case.

- How to get an average value of an object key, based on an array of
  objects.
- How to calculate percentages.
- Aggregating the values into desired information.

Feel free to adjust the values in order to get your desired results, since some of your values weren't really explained.

If you want your percentages to be more precise, you can remove the `Math.round()` method.

If you'd like a case with *n* decimal values in your percent, you could use the `toFixed()` method. However, note that this will automatically convert the return type to `string`. If you expect a number, you'd have to convert it into float with the `parseFloat()` method.

```js
console.log(`string value: ${((4 / 14) * 100).toFixed(2)}`);
console.log(`number value: ${parseFloat(((4 / 14) * 100).toFixed(2))}`);
```

Comment: This doesn't affect your answer, but `Array.prototype.reduce` has been around since ES5, so it has better browser support than ES6. ES5 predates ES6 by six years or so. [ECMAScript 5.1 specification Array.prototype.reduce documentation](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21)

Comment: Oh, I was so sure it was ES6, I stand corrected. Weird that I never really saw it around in the ES5 era. Maybe it wasn't well-known >.>

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for giving me an idea of ​​how to solve it, in the same way I'll use the documentation to improve my logic. Thank you very much again @MarkHanna and Martin

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in the question, you are using the incorrect properties on the array and doing unnecessary DOM updates that cause [reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow) in the browser.

Instead, build up the element you need in memory and only append it to the DOM **once**.

To calculate the total, you can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and use [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to determine the number of reviews.

See comments inline:

```js
const reviews = [{
    review: 2,
    comment: 'Lorem Ipsum'
  },
  {
    review: 4,
    comment: 'Lorem Ipsum'
  },
];

const processReviews = (reviews) => {
  const totalRating = reviews.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue.review, 0);
  const averageRating = Math.round(totalRating / reviews.length); // If the fractional portion of the argument is greater than 0.5, the argument is rounded to the integer with the next higher absolute value.

  // the rest is simply UI
  // create the select element and options
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  const select = document.createElement('select');
  select.className = 'ps-rating reviewsOption';
  select.dataset.readOnly = true;

  fragment.appendChild(select);

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = option.text = i + 1;
    option.selected = (i + 1) === averageRating;

    select.appendChild(option);
  }

  // update the DOM once 
  document.querySelector('.br-theme-fontawesome-stars').appendChild(fragment);

  // debugging
  console.info(`reviews: ${reviews.length}, totalRating: ${totalRating}, average: ${averageRating}`);
}

processReviews(reviews);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="br-theme-fontawesome-stars" />
```